# session cookie and setting path

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-cookies

I have this script that;

1. writes div and paragraph to page
2. creates a random number by time in miliseconds and then adds variables to the end of it.
3. sets those as cookies.

The session cookie does not have the path showing in it the 'expire in 2 years' cookie does have the path. How do I get the path in the session cookie?

```
     <script>
     function func1() {
     document.write("<div class='demo' ><p id='mpuid'></p></div><style>.demo 
     {display:none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1000 }
     </style>");

     } 

     function func2 () {
     document.getElementById("mpuid").innerHTML = new Date().getTime() + '.' 
     + Math.random().toString(36).substring(5);

     }
     function addLoadEvent(func) {
     var oldonload = window.onload;
     if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
     window.onload = func;
     } else {
     window.onload = function() {
     if (oldonload) {
     oldonload();
     }
     func();
     }
     }
     }
     addLoadEvent(func1);
     addLoadEvent(func2);
     addLoadEvent(function() {
     if(Cookies.set('mpuid') == null || Cookies.set('mpuid') == "") {
     Cookies.set('mpuid', value = 
     document.getElementById('mpuid').textContent);
     var myDate = new Date();
     myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 24);
     document.cookie = 'mpuid' +"=" + value + ";expires=" + myDate
              + "path=/";
     }
     })
     </script>

     [cookies being set][1]
```

Comment: You forgot a ";" here : ` document.cookie = 'mpuid' +"=" + value + ";expires=" + myDate
              + "path=/";` and do a "myDate.toGMTString()"

Comment: That part is setting the cookie and path; it is this part that is not; 
         if(Cookies.set('mpuid') == null || Cookies.set('mpuid') == "") {
         Cookies.set('mpuid', value = document.getElementById('mpuid').textContent);

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding this - - - Cookies.set('mpuid', value = document.getElementById('mpuid').textContent, { path: '' });   -------  Before it was creating a session cookie and a date expiration cookie, I am not sure it needed both when adding , {path:"} it now just creates the one cookie with an expiration of 2 years out